# Как можно получить уведомление? (Если добавлено новый запись)

Tags: php

Как можно получить уведомление? (Если добавлено новый запись). 
Например этот код проверяет записи каждый 5 секунд.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.post('feed.php')
    }, 5000);
});
```

**feed.php**

```
<?php
//Как можно реализировать, покажите пример пожалуйста! Заранее спасибо!
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно хранить где-нибудь индекс старый запись. Если же в результате опроса индекс запись больше, чем индекс старый запись, то считаем что это новый запись и сохраняем индекс.